# Can I change this CSS with jQuery or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css

Hey this is super simple, I hope...

Can I use jQuery or JavaScript to change this:

```
.tint:hover:before {  
    background: rgba(0,0,255, 0.5);
}
```

To this:

```
.tint:hover:before {  
    background: rgba(255,0,0, 0.5);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Pseudo-elements are not part of the DOM (Document Object Model), so they can't be manipulated by jQuery or Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Why not have a separate class

```
.newTint:hover:before {
   background: rgba(255,0,0, 0.5);
}
```

Then use jQuery to switch the classes

```
$('#myField').removeClass('tint').addClass('newTint');
```

Comment: Because the value could be "255,255,255, 0.5", "0,0,0, 0.5", or any thing in-between if that makes sense. Perhaps I could create the class first?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can by putting this in your script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.tint:hover:before').css('background',' rgba(255,0,0, 0.5)');
});
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work.

Comment: thats weird, when I try it it  works

Comment: can you give me a link, this page here: